# emails sent by django hitting SPAM filters

Tags: django, email, spam

I've got the following code sending email by django, but all emails are being filters by the receivers SPAM filters. It's my understanding that you can configure django to use an external SMTP server, and I've got an account setup on Google Apps that I hope to use for that purpose.

Is anyone able to help on how to implement this?

```
# conding=utf8

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

from pictures.models import S5Picture
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    def send_mail(self, send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[]):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = send_from
        msg['To'] = send_to
        msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )
        for f in files:
            part = MIMEBase('image', "jpeg")
            part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
            Encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="samsung_gs5_photo.jpg"')
            msg.attach(part)

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'pdf')
        part.set_payload(open('/usr/share/nginx/www/upload/static/BELL_OFFER_WITH_GS5_V3.pdf', 'rb').read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="MMVA_Bell_Offer.pdf"')
        msg.attach(part)

        p = Popen(['/usr/sbin/sendmail', '-t'], stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(msg.as_string())
        p.stdin.close()

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for photo in S5Picture.objects.filter(sent=False):
            try:
                print(photo.email, photo.picture)
                self.send_mail('photo@vps73224.ovh.net', photo.email, 'Your Samsung GS5 Photo!', '', ['/usr/share/nginx/www/upload/static/' + photo.picture])
                photo.sent = True
                photo.save()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
```

Comment: Using a GMail account to send your mail won't necessarily help the spam problem. You should first get proper SPF and DKIM records set up and then see if the problem remains. Configuring SPF and DKIM are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly dependent on the type of content you are trying to send via mail.  It is also highly dependent on your server IP, ISP, and URLs.  It has nothing to do with Django.